# How can you start up RDP and run Selenium Tests?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, rdp

I've received an interesting requirement for my Selenium tests where I need my code to RDP into a server, open up a browser and then run my tests on that.

Initially I thought Browserstack or even Selenium Grid, but the requirement is to actually open the RDP session and run tests through that.

Is there a way to achieve this? I wanted to try using something like Microsoft UI Automation to open the RDP session but then my Selenium tests would just run locally after starting up RDP, right? I'm having some trouble getting starting on this and can't seem to find a good place to start.

Comment: Why does RDP have to be open for Selenium Grid to operate?

Comment: Oh no, Grid was an idea I had for doing this. But the flow as a whole to run the tests would be - run RDP -> open up Chrome -> run tests.

Answer (score 1):

The RDP window is basically an image of a desktop and Selenium cannot control the web browser through it. You would need to deploy your Selenium tests on the remote machine and run them from there.

Comment: So there's no way to actually open up RDP and control the web browser through some sort of Remote driver?

Answer (score 0):

This is theoretically possible, but not exactly in the way you are describing it. You seem to be saying that you want to interact with things inside an RDP windows as if the RDP window were a standard browser or native app, and things inside it were elements in a DOM. By running selenium on a host machine, and then opening up an RDP, and clicking within the RDP window from the original host machine.

It is impossible to connect like this (in a manner that this approach would require) directly over an RDP. If for no other reason than security. For example; if you have ever watched people on youtube infect VM's with crazy viruses to show off the destructive effect of the virus on a VM without hurting the computer they are RDP'ed into from. But there seem to be ways to communicate over TCP connections via RDP, which would facilitate other ways to interact with the remote machine.

Additionally, you could just SSH/Enter-PSSession into the machine, and set up a communication channel between the machines outside of the RDP session. If you had a custom built application on the machine being remoted into, you could use System32 libraries to tell the primary machine x y coordinates of things to click on. Then, from the primary machine, you can maximize the RDP window, and click on the provided X Y coordinates.

I suspect that this would successfully send the click all the way through down to the VM, in the manner you are suggesting. If Appium cannot send the click down in this manner, you may need to develop your own abstraction of the user32.dll to perform clicks using the core Windows logic for keyboards and mouse clicks.

All in all, this is an INSANELY in depth project that accomplishes (seemingly) nothing for the effort. I would push back on whomever is giving you this requirement, by investigating some of the things I mentioned above (along with any other advice), and explaining the cost versus the return on investment.

Hopefully, they will just let you use Selenium Grid to communicate with VM's or attached devices to push out applications and test them given industry standard approaches.

Here is an interesting and relevant read: https://superuser.com/questions/130552/tunneling-a-tcp-ip-connection-through-remote-desktop-connection